# How to use a embeded file as cmd parameter without extracting to hard disk

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cmd, io

How can I use and execute an **embeded resource file** into cmd without copying embeded file to any temp location?

```
Me.proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
Me.proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/U /c REG Import <Embeded Resource>"
```

I think it could be possible using some command line I/O tricks but I don't know exactly how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way to avoid saving the file to a temp location is to write it's contents to the command line - _IF_ that is supported by the target process.

Comment: @VisualVincent But I remember there was an old trick in `cmd` to import and control files from `StandardInput` and use them as parameters. I always forget that as reason of misunderstanding exactly how it works.

Comment: What is the embedded resource? If you want to add it as file name parameter - then you need temp file. Otherwise - put "embedded" resource in command string... Show sample contents of this resource.

Comment: Maybe you want to import .reg file in Registry?

Comment: @i486 Yes I want to import embeded resource into registry; and without copying(extracting) anywhere.

Comment: @idealidea There is special API for Registry. There is no need to call Regedit to import .reg file.

Comment: @i486 I'm also aware of Microsoft.Win32.Registry namespace, but using `reg import` helps to import bulk changes to registry and its easier and faster method in my situation. I also want to learn this because this also may be useful for other similar cmd operations.

Comment: @idealidea There is `Registry` class in .net, not only Win32. `reg import` expects only filename as parameter and for that reason there is no way to do job without file.

Comment: If you use CreateFile you can set it DeleteOnClose. It won't get written to the hard disk (unless you run 1000s of programs).